# Aligning a image button with a background android

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android programming and i was hoping you could help me out with something. I have set a background in an xml file and i am trying to align a image button to a specific area of my background. I have tried using density pixels however it is not precise enough and the button now covers an area of the background i would like to be visible. Any ideas on how i could fix this?

Many thanks,

Alex

My code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/home_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="341dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/workbench" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try using `px` instead of `dp`, however the whole point of `dp` is that they will scale automatically for any screen. If you use `px` I suspect that it will only work well on the current screen resolution that you're testing on. You would have to define `px` values for numerous screen resolutions/densities to ensure that your app displayed correctly across different devices.

Comment: Do you know how i would go about doing that?

Comment: Can you post an image showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you were to separate your logo from the background, that would probably be a lot easier, you could just use a vertical `LinearLayout` or similar.